In VS 2022, in Options | Environment | Fonts and Colors, which option changes the color of multiline comments?
In Visual Studio 2022, we can change the colors of a lot of code source artifacts using the dialog Tools | Options | Environment | Fonts and Colors
Which of these options changes the color of multiline comments? Multiline comments are delimited with /* and */

